# Want to get file size alert for multiple select file field

Tags: file, upload

Have an issue in my page with file upload field.  I knew that the following code will help me out to get the file size alert for single select case...

```
$('.multiFile').bind('change', function () {                        
        alert(this.files[0].size);            
    });
```

But I want to get alert for multiple file size with following code.

HTML code is:

```
<input type="file" class="multiFile" multiple="">
```

Is there any other way around to write?  I tried with the above mentioned jQuery code, but I can get only one file size though I select multiple files in browse window.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what exactly you want. If you want to write the total size for all the files, try this:

```
$('.multiFile').bind('change', function () {                        
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){
        total = total + this.files[i].size;
    }
    alert("Total size: " + total);
});
```

If you want the alert to print all the filesizes:

```
$('.multiFile').bind('change', function () {                        
    var fullText = "File sizes:\n";
    for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){
        fullText = fullText + this.files[i].size;
        if(i < this.files.length - 1)fullText = fullText + "\n";
    }
    alert(fullText);
});
```

Comment: This one is correct solution, I got that.  Although you respond very later this is really appreciated one.  I already found the same kind of code, solved my purpose.  Thanks anyway dude.